# Design a sqlite server client program

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, sockets

I am thinking in implement a test using a sqlite as database, but sqlite dont support server - client architecture. due its, I search using google and find some articles and source code when implement sqlite server - client.

I find it first http://www.sqlitening.com/ is open source but coded in PowerBasic.
later find in google code pages http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3-server-cs/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk  but he dont provide any documentation about usage.

Due its, I think in write my own simple implementation using sockets, but I am afraid in waste my time coding no good or no secure alternative.

my question is, is good idea write a sqlite server - client but using threads? I am afraid with the lock problem inserting data, sqlite allow many connections to read but only one to insert.

I awaiting for your feedback.

Castle.

Comment: If you want a server, why do you want to use sqlite? Why don't you use SQL Server, MySQL or some other DBMS with built in network support?

Comment: sorry is The project is with SQLite I 'cant' use other database server, we think in postgreSQL but was rejected for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it writing my own server implementation. but really is slow sqlite to insert.

10 users all writing 50 registers as same time take 10 seg or more depending network traffic.

I tested using wireless network.

I switched to CUBRID database. but I am testing how to consume stored procedures only has support for java app, and the ado.net driver dont work with CUBRID function/stored procedures (a bug maybe).

Comment: can you share your implementation code of client server over sqlite? thanks

Comment: I made my own implementation too: https://github.com/afsec/concierge-db